# String normalization in pure bash

Tags: bash, unicode, utf-8, freebsd, iconv

The characters 'É' (`E\xcc\x81`) and 'É' (`\xc3\x89`) have different code points. They look identical, yet when testing for a match the result is negative.

Python can normalize them, though: `unicodedata.normalize('NFC', 'É'.decode('utf-8')) == unicodedata.normalize('NFC', 'É'.decode('utf-8'))` returns `True`. And it prints as É.

Question: is there a way to normalize strings in **pure bash***? I've looked into `iconv` but as far as I know it can do a conversion to ascii but no normalization.

*GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14))

Comment: String handling in shells is minimalistic by design. Unicode normalization would just not fit, so I'd be surprised if it were built-in.

Comment: Are you considering `iconv` as "pure bash"? It's just as much an external program as Python.

Comment: Sorry, I meant natively available from the os x shell as per my specs.

Answer (score 4):

If you have [uconv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uconv) available, that'll probably do the job:

```
$ echo -en "E\xcc\x81" | uconv -x Any-NFC | hexdump -C
00000000  c3 89
$ echo -en "\xc3\x89" | uconv -x Any-NFC | hexdump -C
00000000  c3 89
```

`Any-NFD` is also available for the decomposed form.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t (`No available formula with the name "uconv"`)

Comment: Found uconv. It’s part of [icu4c](http://brewformulas.org/Icu4c) and tucked away in `/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/56.1/bin/uconv`. However, I’d be grateful for a native (portable) solution.

Comment: FYI The uconv binary is found in the icu-devtools package in Debian-based Linux distributions.