# ls with umlaut words

Tags: bash, ls

I never used umlaute with ls and came up with this problem:

```
$ ls ba*
ball_1.mp4                ball_partner.mp4          bälle_mit_2.mp4          

$ ls bä*
ls: bä*: No such file or directory

$ ls bäl*
ls: bäl*: No such file or directory

$ ls bal*
ball_1.mp4   ball_partner.mp4
```

Some unconvenient solution for os x:

```
$ basename $(mdfind  bä  -onlyin .)
$ bälle_mit_2.mp4
```

How to get a more bash relevant solution?

Comment: I tried this on my Linux machine and `ls bä*` showed me the file. I did this by copying your `bälle_mit_2.mp4` to a paste buffer, doing `touch <pasted_name>`, then `ls bä*` with the `bä` taken from the original pasted name. So somehow the the original `ä` in the file name, and the one you're entering for `ls` are different. You check `ls | od -c` what the character code is in the name. My `locale` is `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` so that might make a difference in my results.

Comment: What is your `locale` set to?

Comment: In unicode, there are two possibilities to make an `ä`. 1. The original `ä`. 2. An `a` with combining diaeresis (U+0308). Check the representation with `echo ä | hexdump` and `echo b*lle_mit_2.mp4 | hexdump`.

Comment: The thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425326/string-normalization-in-pure-bash
showed me the thematic frame and it seems there is now answer to it? How @lurker said there are two representations of ä '\x61\xcc\x88' and '\xc3\xa4' on my machine. so a more generall solution might be:                     ls $(echo -e '\x62\x61\xcc\x88')*